# Difference between ISV and system integrator partner type?

Tags: partner

When you register as a partner, Partner type is asked by the Salesforce. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sign-up page is pretty clear:

> Salesforce.com has two partner programs. Select your primary program
>   of interest.
>
> - The Independent Software Vendor (ISV) program is for partners who want to **build and sell apps**.
> - The System Integrator (SI) program is for partners who plan to **deliver services** related to salesforce.com.

Apps provide pre-written and packaged functionality intended to be sold to many different customers. Apps can be delivered through the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/).

Services would normally be work - advice, coding, testing, integration - done for a single customer to help them solve their specific problem.

Perhaps someone else can comment on what difference this selection makes to the type of help you get from Salesforce.

Comment: So if I don't intend to sell my app to many different customers through AppExchange. I should register as system integrator?

Comment: @Mudits ... well its "build and sell" so if you are building an app at all that may be the way to go. Perhaps you can add more detail to your question if your situation is not so clear cut. But I assume it is possible to change from one program to the other later on.

Comment: The app I am building is not going to be a salesforce based app (its going to be on python platform) I just need a consumer ID for OAuth for which I have to register as a partner. So which partner type should I register?

Comment: @Mudits I would only be guessing if I picked one or the other. Perhaps you should post another question with this explanation and see if anyone has a recommendation - oh I see you have.